# Remove nth character from filename in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a large number of files in a number of directories with this type of naming convention:

"BU1_KCG_RANDOM_030515.csv", etc.

I need to remove the 16th and 17th characters. So the new file name would be "BU1_KCG_RANDOM_0515.csv".

How can I iterate the multiple directory renaming accordingly?

So far I have got the below, but I am not sure what would come next.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name..................}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using -replace:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Recurse | 
foreach { $_ | rename-item -newname ($_.Name -replace '(.{15})..(.+)','$1$2')  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit basic, eg doesn't check if the file has already been renamed, but should get you to the next step

```
gci -filter *.csv -rec | % { Rename-Item $_ -newname ($_.Name.substring(0,15) + $_.Name.substring(17)) }
```

where

```
gci = get-childitem
% = for-each
$_ = this (inside the for-each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer [mjolinor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098279/remove-nth-character-from-filename-in-powershell/30102497#30102497), but you can always do things in a different way with PowerShell. Since you can index a string like a char array we can use a little array notation to get the characters you want as well.

```
$oldname = "BU1_KCG_RANDOM_030515.csv"
$newname = -join $oldname[0..14 + 17..($oldname.Length)]
$newname
BU1_KCG_RANDOM_0515.csv
```

We also need to use `-join` to convert the array back into a string.